# Writing express middleware to get raw request body before body-parser

Tags: node.js, body-parser

I wrote an Express middleware to retrieve the raw body from the request, and I set it before [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware.

My custom middleware is calling `req.setEncoding('utf8')`, but this causes the following body-parser error:

> Error: stream encoding should not be set
>
> ```
> at readStream (/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:211:17) 
> at getRawBody (/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:106:12)
> at read (/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:76:3)
> at jsonParser (/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:127:5)
> ```

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

function myMiddleware() {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    req.rawBody = '';
    req.setEncoding('utf8');

    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
      req.rawBody += chunk;
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
      next();
    });
  }
}

var app = express();
app.use(myMiddleware());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var listener = app.listen(3000, function() {
});

app.get('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Is there a way to *unset* the encoding? Is there another way to retrieve the raw body, but still use body-parser after it?

Comment: Use your middleware after bodyParser?

Comment: You have a typo in `res.sendStatu(200);` as well.

Comment: Are you sure you need to set the encoding?

Comment: @doublesharp typo fixed, thanks!

Comment: @nicovank If I change the middleware order, my custom middleware hangs. I guess it is because the stream has been already consumed. I am investigating what it could be.

Comment: @doublesharp You are right, I probably do not need to call `setEncoding()`, I thought I was required too, because without it, the app hangs. Now I understand that whoever tries to read the body for second time will hang, in this case *body-parser*.

Comment: Right, because `next()` isn't getting called until after `end` is emitted on the data. Try just setting the event handlers and then calling `next()` at the end, *not* in a handler.

Comment: D'oh, your custom middleware is incorrect. The function inside `myMiddleware` is never getting called, so next is never getting called.

Answer (score 11):

It turns out that [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserrawoptions) has a *verify* option to call a function when the request body has been read. The function receives the body as a buffer.

Here is an example:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

function verifyRequest(req, res, buf, encoding) {
  // The raw body is contained in 'buf'
  console.log( buf.toString( encoding ) );
};

var app = express();
var listener = app.listen(3000);

// Hook 'verifyRequest' with body-parser here.
app.use(bodyParser.json({ verify: verifyRequest }))

app.post('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).send("done!");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You are calling `next()` inside "done", which means the stream has already been consumed. Instead, set up the handler for "data" then pass the request along using `next()`. The "done" event is likely being handled inside `bodyParser` so after it executes you have access to `req.rawBody`. If this was not the case you would add another middleware that calls `next()` inside a `req.on('done')` to hold the rest from processing until you have all the data.

```
// custom middleware - req, res, next must be arguments on the top level function
function myMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  req.rawBody = '';

  req.on('data', function(chunk) {
    req.rawBody += chunk;
  });

  // call next() outside of 'end' after setting 'data' handler
  next();  
}

// your middleware
app.use(myMiddleware);

// bodyparser
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// test that it worked
function afterMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.rawBody);
  next();  
}

app.use(afterMiddleware);
```

If you need to access the raw body you might also want to look into [`bodyParser.raw()`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserrawoptions). This will put the raw body into `req.body`, same as `bodyParse.json()` but can be made to run conditionally based on the content type - check out `options.type`.

Comment: `in your example the inner function is never being called` yes it is.... the function `myMiddleware` is returning the function and he calls it later `app.use(myMiddleware())`

Comment: You are correct, but it isn't passing in `req, res, next` so they aren't executed in the right context

Comment: Writing the middleware handler as an inner function, allow callers to pass parameter-options to the middleware during setup time.

Comment: I have a new problem with this solution, `app.get('/', function (req, res) { })` is not being called anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a different approach, since your current approach actually consumes the message and makes it impossible for body-parser to read it (and there are a bunch of edge case bugs that spring up by calling `next` synchronously):

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.text({type: '*/*'}));
```

This will read any `application/json` request as JSON, and everything else as text.

If you must have the JSON object in addition to the text, I recommend parsing it yourself:

```
app.use(bodyParser.text({type: '*/*'}));
app.use(myMiddleware);

function myMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    req.rawBody = req.body;
    if(req.headers['content-type'] === 'application/json') {
        req.body = JSON.parse(req.body);
    }
    next();
}
```

Comment: I think parsing it myself will be the way to go.