# In new express where body-parser is implicit, how to get raw request body in middleware?

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to get the raw request body in one of my middlewares in my Express app. There are a few posts on Stackoverflow that show how to do this (e.g. [Node.js - get raw request body using Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710225/node-js-get-raw-request-body-using-express) or [Writing express middleware to get raw request body before body-parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40637975/writing-express-middleware-to-get-raw-request-body-before-body-parser)), but:

- They use body-parser, which I believe is built-in with the new Express version, so am not sure how to use it in this case
- They extract the raw request in `app.use()`, which means that all routes would extract the raw request, whereas I only want to extract it in one route (more specifically, in an independent middleware that's buried deep in my code rather than in `app.js`, to which I want to be able to just pass the `req` element and extract its raw body there).

Any advice on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have not already parsed the body before reaching this route (using body-parser or something similar), following will work in your routes file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.get('/path', bodyParser.raw(options), (req,res){
   //your code
});
```

bodyParser.raw(options) will return a function that accepts 3 arguments (req,res,next) and the raw body will become available in req.body

Comment: Nice, thank you @singh_arpit, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Do I still have to include `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');` with the newer versions of express?

Comment: I could not confirm that body parser is included as an API of the latest expressJS version. As per this https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body, you have to include it.

Comment: Thanks! One last question: how do I know whether I've already parsed the body or not?

Comment: req.body is by default undefined. If it is not, it means body-parser did its work